# Comparing count(*) with select for one result

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table `tb_xyz` having  field1, field2 as indexed.

Now I have two queries:

```
SELECT `id` 
FROM `tb_xyz` force index(field1, field2, date_utc) 
WHERE `field1`=472
  AND `field2`=49066
  AND `date_utc` >= DATE(NOW() - interval 1 day)
  AND `date_utc` <= DATE(NOW() + interval 1 day)
  AND `status` NOT IN (1,4,6) 
LIMIT 1
```

and

```
SELECT count(*) AS cnt
FROM `tb_xyz` force index(user_id, fleet_id, job_date_utc)
WHERE `field1`=472
  AND `field2`=49066
  AND `date_utc` >= date(now() - interval 1 day)
  AND `date_utc` <= date(now() + interval 1 day)
  AND `status` NOT IN (1,4,6)
```

Assuming both queries are written to just check if this condition is met at least once.
Which of them is more optimal. I tried checking for their execution times, but results were mixed, for small data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first query (`SELECT ... LIMIT 1`) will perform better as it can stop scanning the table as soon as it finds a matching row while the `COUNT(*)` query will have to scan the entire table to compute its result. You may find that using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM `tb_xyz` force index(user_id, fleet_id, job_date_utc)
    WHERE `field1`=472
      AND `field2`=49066
      AND `date_utc` >= date(now() - interval 1 day)
      AND `date_utc` <= date(now() + interval 1 day)
      AND `status` NOT IN (1,4,6)
)
```

is even more efficient than the `LIMIT` query; looking at your execution plan (from `EXPLAIN <query>`) will let you know if there's a difference between the two which might cause a performance difference.